# How to print Array Values on one line, not in a sequence

Tags: java, arrays, println

This is from Chapter 10, problem 10 of my "Art and Science of Java" book from Stanford( I am a full time physician teaching myself the intro to programming methodology using Java in my spare time[Python is my real goal for future medical research projects], so I am a bloody beginner). I have no mentors in programming and I would like your help.

The exercise: input a string into the array. I solved the problem of array filling.

The problem: I filled the my 2d array with data, no problem, but how do I print the results of the array in a row to make it look like a checkers board? "b" stands for "black" checkers on half of the board.

The output should be:

```
 b b b b 
b b b b
 b b b b
etc....
```

All of my p's end up being printed in 1 column, not in a row, this is the output and my problem:

b

b

b

b

b

etc...

My code:

```
public void run() {
setFont("Helvetica-40");

displayCheckerboard(setBoard());    

}

private String[][] setBoard() {


for (int row = 0; row<8; row++) {

for (int col =0; col<8; col++) {

    if (row == 0 && col %2 ==0) {

     cBoard[row][col]= "  ";

        } else if (row==0 && col%2!=0) {
        cBoard[row][col]= "b";

        }else if (row==1 && col %2!=0) {
                cBoard[row][col]= "  ";
        }  else if (row==1 && col%2==0) {
            cBoard[row][col]= "b";

        } else if (row ==2&& col%2 !=0) {
            cBoard[row][col]= "b";
        } else if( row == 2 && col%2 ==0) {
                cBoard[row][col]= "  ";
        } else if (row ==3&& col%2 ==0) {
            cBoard[row][col]= " -";
        } else if( row == 3 && col%2!=0) {
                cBoard[row][col]= "  ";
        }
        //....continue here if code works...
    }

}
return cBoard;
}

private void displayCheckerboard(String board[][]) {

for (int row=0; row<8; row++) {
    for (int col=0;col<8; col++) {
        print(board[row][col]);

    }

    }

}

String cBoard[][] = new String[8][8];

}
```

Comment: What is `print()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using System.out.**println**() which prints a new line every time you call it. If you want to print multiple times without a new line for every string use System.out.**print**()
This way you could write your program as

```
for (int row=0; row<8; row++) {
for (int col=0;col<8; col++) {
    System.out.print(board[row][col]);
    }
System.out.println()     //go to next line after every row
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea is saving all the values in a string variable when you're done you print out the string. For each inner-loop iteration the value you get would be appended to the string variable **str**.
This would do the trick.

```
String str ="";

for (int row=0; row<8; row++) {
    for (int col=0;col<8; col++) {
        str += "  "+board[row][col];
    }
     print(str); // prints values in row
}
```